# What to replace in "$dir -name" to access directory?

Tags: python, replace, directory, wav, file-extension

I need to use this script to convert .aup files. However, I'm confused about what I should fill in here: "$dir -name". For example, the directory that the .aup files are in is called cohort2. What should I replace in the code with the name of my directory? Thanks!

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script reads in .aup files, converts them to .wav files, writing
# them to the same directory as the .aup files

# run this as scripts/multi-wav05 dir/to/aupfiles 

#dir=$1

find $dir -name \*.aup | while read f; do 
    b=`basename $f .aup` 
    d=`dirname $f`
    echo $d $b
    ./aup2wav --chan 1 $f $d $b 
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like if you uncomment `#dir=$1` => `dir=$1` you then should be able to run this script like this `script_name.sh ./cohort2`.

`$dir` is just an argument. And in script `find` command takes path as a parameter which is taken from script arguments. Or you can just replace `$dir` with `./cohort2` or full path to `cohort2` folder.

Comment: Hi Ivan thanks for your reply. When I uncomment dir=$1 then I get an error message regarding that line. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @KatieMudd What error do you get? if I put `dir=$1  echo dir` in script it runs ok I see argument in output.

Comment: Here's what I've tried: `dir=$1 echo dir` and then `find cohort2 -name \*.aup | while read f; do` . The error message that I get is SyntaxError: invalid syntax, pointing to the '$' in `dir=$1`

Comment: @KatieMudd I see it's python, is `aup2wav` a python script or shell script? I thought you're running a shell script, and for shell script $1 is a right way to get arguments. So what happens if you just run it as a shell script (without `python`)? In this case you may be need to add `python` before `./aup2wav` if it's a python script.

Comment: I mean what you have posted above is purely shell script, so you just run it like `./script_name.sh ./cohort2`, not in python.

Comment: Ah yes I see. I was under the impression that this script should be used in python. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help, please consider accepting the answer by clicking the check-mark, thanks.